# Как создать таблицу из нескольких списков

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

в шаблон html приходит питоновский кортеж вида `([1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['d', 'e', 'f'])`, как из этого используя шаблонизатор jinja2 сделать таблицу в html?

Такую=)

```
|1|A|d|

|2|B|e|

|3|C|f|
```

Comment: Вот простое и вполне понятное [руководство](https://proglib.io/p/rukovodstvo-dlya-nachinayushchih-po-shablonam-jinja-v-flask-2022-09-05)